# How can I make a update prepared statement work in JavaScript in Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, inquirerjs

```
.then(function (val) {
      var roleId = roleArr.indexOf(val.role) + 1;
      db.query(
        'UPDATE employee SET role_id = ? WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?;',
        [roleId, val.firstname, val.lastName],
        function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.table(val);
          startPrompt();
        }
      );
    });
```

This code comes from an inquirer statement. The roleID, val.firstname, and val.lastName are good variables because they are tested elsewhere in the program. The update statement is not updating though. I tried it with doublequotes around the where statement variables but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? The same statement works in a mysql shell.

Comment: Error messages?

Comment: How do I console log the query results?

Comment: No error messages just doesn't run the query.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to get the id of the name I wanted to change instead of matching a first_name and last_name.

```
var nameArr = [];
function Name() {
  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM employee",
    function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        nameArr.push(res[i].first_name + " " + res[i].last_name);
      }
    });
  return nameArr;
}
```

and

```
var nameId = nameArr.indexOf(val.name) + 1;
```

Then I used the Name() to get the choices for the inquirer question.